# Missing number, treated as zero in \label

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using \label after \addplot to build a custom legend later on, and getting this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@section 
l.17 \label{plot1}
              ;
```

The source code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
width=0.951\fwidth,
height=\fheight,
at={(0\fwidth,0\fheight)},
]

\addplot []
table[row sep=crcr]{%
    -6.0000 -4.0899\\
    -3.0000 0.6108\\
    -1.0000 2.3684\\
    1.0000  4.0699\\
    3.0000  5.6297\\
};
\label{plot1};

\end{axis};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You cannot put `\label` anywhere, it has to be used after a counter has been incremented. Here, the `\label` should be called after the use of `\caption` to add a legend to your figure.

Comment: @KersouMan `pgplots` offers  a `\label` feature for plots. So `\label` can be used after `\addplot`.  The example in the question works for me, if I complete it with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` and a definition of `\fwidth` and `\fheight`.